# iOS: How to send key to UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I have implemented a custom keyboard view in an iOS application.  I have several UITextFields that use this keyboard.  Some of these UITextFields have delegates that override `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.  However if my keyboard just sets the text value in the text field, the shouldChangeCharactersInRange message is not sent.  What I think I need is to actually do something like SendKey and send the key code to the UITextField.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

[As I note in my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9217158/8047), the `UITextField` conforms to the `UITextInput` protocol. So you call its methods:

```
[textField replaceRange:textField.selectedTextRange withText:text];
```

Of interest: `""` will perform a backspace and, of course, `" "` will do a space.

This should call the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method automatically. If not, you'd have to do that yourself.

**You definitely need to do this if you are going to create a custom keyboard on iOS.**

Comment: I was looking for a way to delete single characters from a UITextField by ways of pressing a custom UIButton, even if the cursor is *not* at the end of the text field. This answer does just that (kudos for the "Of interest..." part), thanks a million (+1)!

Comment: `[textField replaceRange:textField.selectedTextRange withText:text]` does not call `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like the keyboard is responsible for sending the shouldChangeCharactersInRange message to the UITextField itself, rather than just setting its value. Have your keyboard compute the values of `range` and `string`, and call:

```
if ([[theTextField delegate] textField:theTextField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:range replacementString:string])
    theTextField.text = [theTextField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
```

Comment: it doesn't seem that I can get the range.  I don't see how to get the cursor position, or range of characters selected, if any.

Comment: Try just using the entire range of the text in the field, as follows: `NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, theTextField.text.length);`

Comment: It seems like an awkward work around to change the entire text when a single key is pressed, but it may work.  Now my problem is I don't know where the cursor position is to insert the character.  If I knew the cursor position, I could also send the correct range.