# Custom Keyboard on iOS: How do I access the UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a `UIView` subclass that I assign to a text field as follows:

```
self.textField.inputView = [[HexKeyboard alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
```

and this works (i.e., the keyboard comes up). **However, how should the `HexKeyboard` instance know about the `textField`?**

[Of course I can add a property to the `HexKeyboard` to achieve this (and call it `delegate`), but I figure there's a built-in mechanism for this...]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no built-in mechanism for this, as the other answerers have pointed out. As Nick says, you don't need a complex delegate pattern for this. Or rather, you use the delegate pattern, but you get the delegate class for free. In this case it's the `UITextInput` protocol.

So your keyboard probably looks like this (and has a NIB)

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

// use assign if < iOS 5
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet id <UITextInput> *delegate;

@end
```

When you create the keyboard controller, you assign the `UITextInput` conformer to it, so something like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    HexKeyboardController *keyboardController = [[HexKeyboardController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HexKeyboardController" bundle:nil];
    self.textField.inputView = keyboardController.view;
    keyboardController.delegate = self.textField;

}
```

However, I thought, there MUST be a way to define this keyboard just once and get the keyboard to "automatically know" who the `UITextInput` object that summoned it is. But I've looked around to no avail... you cannot figure out who the `firstResponder` is unless you troll the view hierarchy yourself or retain your delegates in a list (which would cause a retain loop). **Plus, this isn't so bad because the HexKeyboardController will unload, too, when the `textField` is dealloced.**

Comment: I don't t get the "use assign if < iOS5" comment - iOS5 doesn't protect you from retain cycles if you use retain, and assign under iOS4 is not equivalent to retain under iOS5.

Comment: Hi @NickLockwood, I beat you to the punch by 24 seconds on my edit :) Seriously, my apologies, my code was wrong.

Comment: Heh, damn iPhone keyboard - too slow to type comments!

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need a complex delegate pattern for this. Just create a property of type UITextField on your HexKeyboard class, and make it an unsafe_unretained reference so you don't get a retain loop:

```
@interface HexKeyboard

@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) UITextField *textField;

@end
```

Then set it when you set your inputView:

```
self.textField.inputView = [[HexKeyboard alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
self.textField.inputView.textField = self.textField;
```

Comment: Why `unsafe_unretained` instead of weak?

Comment: Weak is iOS5 only. If you only plan to support iOS5, use weak instead. If you need to support iOS4, use unsafe_unretained.

Comment: Thanks. What's the advantage over `assign`, which also works on iOS4?

Comment: Assign can't be used for object properties if you're using ARC. If you aren't using ARC it makes no difference if you use assign or unsafe_unretained.

Comment: You may use `assign` for objects with ARC just like without ARC. Delegates are typically `assign`, not `unsafe_unretained`, only because the new keyword was introduced with iOS 5 (and whatever on the Mac side), and programming is, by convention, conventional. If you include the word "delegate" in the property name, the user knows that it's not going to be retained, and also what it's for.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it gave me a compiler warning when I tried it, and if you run the ARC conversion tool it changes assign to unsafe_unretained. Good point about calling it delegate though, although that also implies it will be a protocol rather than a concrete class, so may be misleading in another way.

Comment: I checked the docs and I think you're right - it's fine to use assign for unretained properties (but not for ivars, that was where my compiler warning came from).

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is a built in mechanism for this, you probably want the a delegate in the hex keyboard that will receive the "keystrokes" from it and then append it to the textfield, or whatever it is you need to do..